# Why do segments of my print "pop" off the bed after a few layers?

Tags: creality-ender-3, pla, filament

I just received delivery of some new filament and after a few layers of printing some segments will start to "pop" off the bed.

I've calibrated esteps and levelled bed. It only seems to happen with this new filament

Comment: Please [edit] in some pictures to better assess the problem and offer a solution.

Comment: What filament (I suspect PLA as it is tagged), please also add printing parameters like temperatures and speeds. What print surface do you use, glass or a coated sheet.

Comment: Welcome to 3D Printing Stack Exchange.  This question is a duplicate -- there are multiple questions around about "why are my prints lifting" or similar adhesion related issues.

Comment: Hi there jaywayco and welcome to SE.3DP. Unfortunately, I'm going to cast the final vote that this is a duplicate, which will cause it to be closed. However, if you can edit the question to make it differ from the proposed duplicate, then it may get reopened... Top marks for the Terry Tibbs avatar though... :-)

Comment: I should have added that if you don't feel that your question has been answered by the proposed duplicate then *please* add the extra requested info,  and leave a comment saying so and/or click on the flag link beneath the question. That way  your question can be re-opened.